# Can you use a function within index.html of flask application in this instance?

Tags: python, html, flask

What I am trying to accomplish is checking a returned python string with this function:

```
def set_check(s):
        checks = ['Irons', 'Set', 'set', 'irons']
        if any(x in s for x in checks) or re.search(r'\d-[A-Z]', s) or re.search(r'\d\s-\s[A-Z]', s):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I am trying to add a div object IF the conditional returns as True.

For example:

```
{% if set_check(results[i]['name'])%                               <div class="set">SET</div> 
{% endif %}
```

for context this is within a for loop and is parsing a json list.

Is this possible or can someone suggest a better approach? thankyou.

I have attempted to pass the function through render_templates which was very uninformed of me haha

Answer (score 0):

You can use [context processors](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templating/#context-processors), which will make a function available to jinja2 templates.

```py
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def set_check(s):
        checks = ['Irons', 'Set', 'set', 'irons']
        if any(x in s for x in checks) or re.search(r'\d-[A-Z]', s) or re.search(r'\d\s-\s[A-Z]', s):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return dict(set_check=set_check)
```

```html
{% if set_check(results[i]['name']) %}
<p>{{ results[i]['name'] }} is in the list of `checks`!</p>
{% endif %}
```